# Razer Mamba left-click doesn't stay pressed when I hold it

Tags: mouse-click, mouse-buttons, razer-mouse

I have no idea how this just started to happen. Whenever I play a game and I'm supposed to hold the left button down the mouse/game/OS releases the button when I'm still holding it down.

It also occurs whenever I drag a file from one point to another on my screen. It's really irritating and I tried to contact Razer Support. They told me to update firmware and it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try another mouse? Have you any AutoHotkey or AutoIt scripts running?

Comment: It's probably broken. Have you tried it on another computer?

Comment: I've tried another mouse, It worked perfectly. I currently dont have another computer at the moment :(

Comment: Most likely the microswitch for the left mouse button is broken, then. What's Razer's warranty like?